# Help with integral $\int_0^y x^{-\alpha} (y-x)^{-\alpha} dx$

Tags: convolution

How should I proceed to work out following convolution integral:

$\int_0^y   x^{-\alpha} (y-x)^{-\alpha} dx$

for real $\alpha$ > 0.

It is the convolution of a powerlaw decaying impulse response with itself. My goal is to find the decay exponent of the autocorrelation function.

Comment: You mean $0<\alpha<1$, since for $\alpha>1$ there is no solution.

Comment: Thank you, very relevant to my cause ! Could you explain how you concluded this?

Comment: $1/x^\alpha$ is not integrable in the vicinity of zero in that case, since its integral would be $x^{1-\alpha}$ which is infinite if $\alpha>1$. Analogous reason in the vicinity of $x=y$.

Comment: @Marcel: Dear Marcel, how would the conclusion "no solution for $\alpha > 1$" change if the limits were not [0, $y$] but rather [c > 0, $y$] ? The impulse response originates from a Pareto distribution which I forgot is defined only above a minimum value.

Comment: Conclusion still holds, because of the upper limit.You can have $\alpha>1$ if you integrate in $[c,d]$ with $c>0$ and $d<y$.

Comment: @Marcel: Does that mean, for $\alpha>1$, that the $1-2\alpha$ decay from answer below, is at least approximately correct for $t_{min}/t_{max}$ very small ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rescale with $x=yt$, then

$$\int_0^y   x^{-\alpha} (y-x)^{-\alpha} dx=\int_0^1   (yt)^{-\alpha} (y-yt)^{-\alpha} y\,dt=y^{1-2\alpha}\int_0^1   t^{-\alpha} (1-t)^{-\alpha}\,dt\\
=y^{1-2\alpha}B(1-\alpha,1-\alpha).$$

Comment: Thank you! Please would you confirm that the solution thus decays as ~ $y^{1-2 \alpha}$? Beta function is just acting as a constant right?

Comment: @user3817704: in terms of $y$ or in terms of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: In terms of $y$. Impulse response was defined IRF($y$) = $y^{-\alpha}$ and I need to express the powerlaw decay of autocorrelation in terms of $\alpha$ parameter.

Comment: @user3817704: the answer should be obvious to you.

Comment: Dear Yves, I think I understand it correctly. Just that my question serves a project at work and I want explicit confirmations that what I do is correct. Anyway, I thank you sincerely for you answer, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hint write it as $(xy-x^2)^{-\alpha}dx$ now y is a constant as variable is x which is easy to integrate.

Comment: Ya i edited it thanks

Comment: I think the OP will need more help than this. Why is this easy?

Comment: You already gave the reasons so dint write anything

Comment: Yes please indicate some more steps, I do not see how to proceed after rewriting.

Comment: Should I approximate the integrand by generalised binomial theorem? Or can I solve it exactly? Please more help.

Comment: Start by writing $x=zy$ to get rid of the $y$ and get an integral over $z$. Then look up the Beta Function in Wikipedia

Comment: Oh, there is an answer now saying exactly this!